# How do export Meshes separately?

Tags: export

So basically I'm trying to figure out how to separately export the meshes from a single model. For example, I made a katana using multiple different Shapes by pressing add. Now I tried to export each part of the mesh separately by selecting it on the explorer but that still exports the whole thing. I've been trying to figure this out for multiple days, please help me.

Comment: I don`t know if it`s possible to export just one mesh, but you can inport it to a new file using file -> append, this way you can select any object to import from another file.

Comment: Hello, please specify in which format you want to export. I know fbx has a batch mode that creates a folder for each model for instance